# My Samba share isnt asking for username and password when connecting

Tags: networking, server, windows, password, samba

When I go to add a network drive, after I enter the ip address and share name, it automatically adds the drive without asking for the username and password. I created a username for samba already

This is my conf info

```
[share]
path = /home/cfarida/share
read only = no
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
```

I had this working before, but i reinstalled Ubuntu after adding some more drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a big assumption here but ....

Your use of the term "network drive" implies the client is Windows. Did the samba user you add match the Windows user's username and password. If you did then what you are experiencing is normal. Windows automatically passes the current user's name and password when it tries to connect to a share. If they match what you set in samba then access is seamless. It will also remember the correct credentials it used the last time it accessed the server.

You can test that if you want. Temporarily disable the samba user:

```
sudo smbpasswd -d username
```

Then try to access the share. You should be prompted for credentials.

*Note: To re-enable the samba user:*

```
sudo smbpasswd -e username
```

Comment: That seems to have been the reason. Thanks so much for the help!!!